# Geoserver WMS and filtering tables with cyrillic column names

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, wfs

I try to serve PostGIS tables with Geoserver WMS (both 2.1 and 2.2). Some column names are in cyrillic.

Problem is - service fails, when I try to filter by those cyrillic columns (both with CQL and regular, XML-based filters). For example:

```
FILTER=<Filter><PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>Магазин</PropertyName><Literal>1</Literal></PropertyIsGreaterThan></Filter>
```

or

```
CQL_FILTER=Магазин=10
```

As result, I get

```
<ServiceException code="internalError">
    Rendering process failed
    Property &apos;??????&apos; could not be found in magasiin
</ServiceException>
```

or

```
<ServiceException>
    Could not parse CQL filter list. Lexical error at line 1, column 1.
    Encountered: &quot;\u0430&quot; (1072), after : &quot;&quot; Parsing : ??????=10.
</ServiceException>
```

I can't find clear answer from Google. Closest posting is http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOS-4177 that claims, it's bug and it's fixed, but apparently it's not working in my case.

When I get confirmation, it's problem of Geoserver, then onliest solution seems to renaming of those columns.

Also, WFS service seems to fail always (despite of filtering), when at least on column name is in cyrillic.